# Changing tables rows to links

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change the rows output by PHP in a table to links. I have added the a href tags to the example below, however it results in an unexpected `T_VARIABLE`. I have tried it without the extra quotes, but this displays a blank table. I am not sure what the flaw in the logic is.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td><a href="$cell"</a></td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes as that is your string delimiter.

```
 echo "<td><a href=\"$cell\">Link</a></td>";
```

Or use single quotes

```
 echo '<td><a href="' . $cell .'">Link</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the double quotes:

```
foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td><a href=\"{$cell}\"</a></td>";
```

By the way, I think that a good habit is to sorround variables inside strings with the curly braces to improve readibility of the code.

Comment: You missed the second mistake, it won't error in PHP but will give flawed HTML. There's a missing > and content of the HREF element.

Comment: You are right, I focused on the php part and didn't notice the html error :)